# Instantiating an object of a type parameter using reflections

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I know that when working with Generics we can't instantiate an object of unknown type i.e the statment :
T var = new T() will give compile time error , I tried it using Reflections after some search , but its not compiling and gives me the error I will mention at the end

Code :

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        Pair<Integer> obj = new Pair<Integer>(Integer.class);
                            obj.<Integer>func();             
    }
}
class Pair<T>
{
    T  var;
   <T> Pair(){}
   <T> Pair(Class<T> reflection){
             var = reflection.newInstance() ;  
             }

   <T> void func(){
   System.out.println(var);
   }
}
```

Error :

```
HelloWorld.java:12: error: incompatible types: T#1 cannot be converted to T#2
             var = reflection.newInstance() ;  
                                         ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in constructor <T#1>Pair(Class<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in class Pair
```

I am trying to find the cause of the error but can't reach it

Comment: If you've defined `T` as a generic of `Pair` class, you should not define it for each method in this class.

Comment: What is the purpose of `<T>` in `<T> Pair(){}` and `<T> Pair(Class<T> reflection){..}`? It defines *separate* generic type for those construction, so `T` there can be different than one defined at `class Pair<T>`.

Comment: Why not just use `Supplier<T>`? Or, just pass a `T` directly?

Comment: I removed it ... but another error apeared

Comment: @Andy Turner can you elaborate more what you mean

Comment: Well, `newInstance` may throw some exceptions, you are probably asked to handle or rethrow them.

Comment: @Pshemo yes thats what actually happened

Comment: Then do so. We don't know how you want to handle them...

Comment: @Pshemo I don't know .. just meant you are correct and that error is what actually after removing the extra T you all told me about :D .. I was stuck at the begining but ur advice to remove T helped alot in realizing the real problem

Comment: I am trying the Supplier<T> now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Pair<T>
{
    T  var;
   <T> Pair(){}
   <T> Pair(Class<T> reflection){
             var = reflection.newInstance() ;  
             }

   <T> void func(){
   System.out.println(var);
   }
}
```

The `<T>`s on the constructors and method are defining another type variable which hides the one on the class. They are all called "`T`", but they're different types.

(The ones on the zero-arg constructor and `func` are unused anyway).

Remove these extra type variable declarations.

```
class Pair<T> {
  T var;

  Pair() {}

  Pair(Class<T> reflection) {
    var = reflection.newInstance();
  }

  void func() {
    System.out.println(var);
  }
}
```

Then you just have to deal with the fact that not all classes have accessible zero-arg constructors; and that `newInstance()` throws checked exceptions that you would need to handle.

A better approach would be to provide a `Supplier<T>`:

```
  Pair(Supplier<T> reflection) {
    var = reflection.get();
  }
```

Comment: yes , I used lambda expression from the caller to provide an implementation for the supplier interface .. it worked well ..thnx for all of you

Comment: And `newInstance()` may throw undeclared checked exceptions thrown by the constructor. That’s why it has been deprecated in Java 9. Developers should use `getConstructor().newInstance()`. This forces the caller to handle another checked exception, `InvocationTargetException`, but prevents missing an exception that must be handled. All those checked exceptions can be handled uniformly by catching and handling `ReflectiveOperationException`. Of course, `Supplier` simplifies things dramatically. Should be noted that the caller only needs to change `SomeActualType.class` to `SomeActualType::new`…